# Does the CPT theorem imply $CP=T$?

Tags: special-relativity, operators, spin-statistics, cp-violation, cpt-symmetry

Does the [CPT theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPT_symmetry) imply $CP=T$?

That is, does it imply that the action of Charge Conjugation and Parity inversion on some representation of the Lorentz group, is *the same as* doing a [time reversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-symmetry)?

Specifically, given explicit expressions for $P$ and $C$ (in terms of matrices and complex conjugation) in some basis, how does $CP$ relate to the expression for $T$ and $T^{-1}$

Comment: Is the question if $T^2=1$?

Comment: @Qmechanic I suppose partly. More so how does CP relate to $T^{-1}$ relate to $T$

Comment: Why would you think it implies that? Presenting your reasoning will make it clearer to answerers what they need to explain.

Comment: @ACuriousMind For what it's worth, I had an old book with outdated formalism for the $T$ operator, and the fog was cleared for me by Schwartz "Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model" who discusses both and reasons the modern $T$ (Wigners $T$) is better and not trivially $(CP)^{-1}$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The assertion of the CPT theorem is that, under natural hypotheses, *the Hamiltonian $H$ operator of a theory is invariant under the simultaneous action of the symmetries  (in Wigner's sense i.e. unitary/antiunitary operators) C, P, and T*.
$$CPT H (CPT)^{-1} = H\:.\tag{1}$$
This action can also be implemented by a direct action on the quantum fields the Hamiltonian is made of. However, the fact that the Hamiltonian is CPT invariant does not imply a precise relation between CP and T, since their combination is equivalent to the identity **when they act on the Hamiltonian**, not in general.

In particular, $CP=T$ or $T^{-1}$ do not make sense (also including phases), since the left hand side is linear and the right hand side is anti linear, when viewing them as *operators* in the Hilbert space as in Eq.(1).

However, from the above reasoning it is evident  that

*the action of T on the Hamiltonian is the same as the combined action of CP on the Hamiltonian.*

Comment: I am using my phone. It is quite difficult!

Comment: No problem. I edited it a bit.

Comment: Thank you, please fix all typos.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, however I've been taught C is anti-unitary, since it applies a complex conjugation followed by a linear transform. Is this not the case?

Comment: If you are dealing with operators in Hilbert space,  C is unitary, thus linear.  If you instead consider fields, C is antilinear, but T is linear...

Comment: @Valter Moretti Weird! Do you know any good books which explore that difference? Is it related to infinite vs finite dimensional representations of the Lorentz group?

Comment: Yes it is related to that. Try "PCT, spin statistics, and all that"

Comment: ...Maybe it is even different, I do not remember well now (I handled these issues when I was student), but I remember that there are differences when dealing with the formalism in the Hilbert space rather than referring to  representations of fields.

Comment: The point is the way to act on linear combinations $a\Psi + b \Phi$. This is different for T and C  depending on the interpretation of these fields, field operators vs simple fields.

Comment: Is this the same as saying the commutator $[CPT, H] = 0$?

Comment: Yes it is: $CPT H (CPT)^{-1}-H=0$ is equivalent to $CPT H -H CPT=0$ (just by multiplying both sides with $CPT$ on the right). It is also equivalent to $CPT U_t = U_{-t}CPT$ where $U_t = e^{-iH}$ is the time evolutor.